# Mapply with margin in R

Tags: r, apply, mapply

I need to apply a function that takes two arguments on matrices.

```
mapply(function(x, y) x+y, rbind(1:3, 1:3), rbind(2:4, 2:4))
```

output is

```
[1] 3 3 5 5 7 7
```

which doesn't give me the desired format I want. I need it to retain its matrix form.

On the other hand, **apply** function in R has an argument **margin** which helps retain the matrix format but only applies to one argument.

```
apply(rbind(1:3,1:3), MARGIN = c(1,2), function(x) x+3)

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    4    5    6
[2,]    4    5    6
```

The point is there's a **MARGIN** argument for **apply** and not something like it for **mapply** or is there ?

PLEASE: I don't require an answer to rearrange the result, I can do it. I am using this piece of code to write a function that takes a three dimensional meshgrid which will be hassle to rearrange.

EDITED LATER:

I am really sorry, I didn't elaborate this,
Of course, I am not stuck because I wanna do

```
rbind(1:3, 1:3) + rbind(2:4, 2:4)
```

These **rbinds** are just examples of the vectors I am using. And the **function(x, y) x+y** is also an example of very long nested functions that I can't just copy here which will be so confusing and inefficient. But it is a function of two variables which is relevant for now.

Comment: what is your expected output?  By doing `rbind`, you are actually passing a matrix as each argument to `mapply`.  So, the elementwise addition happens here

Comment: BTW, for this example, you don't need `mapply` i.e. `rbind(1:3, 1:3) + rbind(2:4, 2:4)`, but for 3D grid, you may need to loop through the sequence of one of the dimensions and then do the sum.  I guess it can be done with `sapply/lapply`.

Comment: `m <- matrix(NA, 2, 3); m[] <- mapply(function(x, y) x+y, rbind(1:3, 1:3), rbind(2:4, 2:4)) `

Comment: And with s/vapply: `x <- rbind(1:3, 1:3); y <- rbind(2:4, 2:4); sapply(seq_len(ncol(x)), function(i) x[,i]+y[,i])` OR `vapply(seq_len(ncol(x)), function(i) x[,i]+y[,i], FUN.VALUE = numeric(nrow(x)))`

Comment: `apply()` operates on matrices, which have margins. `mapply()` operates on vectors or lists of vectors, which don't have margins.  That's why there is no `MARGIN` argument to `mapply()`.